# Pylint throws a error and won't allow me to import functions to my file

Tags: python, python-unittest, pylint

```
import unittest

from machinetranslation.translator import english_to_french, french_to_english

class TestMyModule(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_english_to_french(self):

        self.assertNotEqual(english_to_french("None"), "")

        self.assertEqual(english_to_french('Hello'), 'Bonjour')

    def test_french_to_english(self):

        self.assertNotEqual(french_to_english("None"), "")

        self.assertEqual(french_to_english('Bonjour'), 'Hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In my test file I am calling my other file which is in the same folder and directory, but Pylint throws an error of "Unable to import 'machinetranslation.translator'pylint(import-error)". I tried taking away the .machinetranslation from the translator.py when calling it but it throws the same error. Does anyone know if I called it wrong or if its a Pylint thing?

Here is my other file in which I am trying to import the functions from:

```py
import os
import json
import six
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from google.cloud import translate


#Api key and url


apikey = os.environ['AIzaSyC8ZLEGytCqTMcqvFV0AVh0wCEgBkRlHr4']

url = os.environ['https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=ferrous-amphora-352613']

#Translates english to french
# Initialize Translation client
def english_to_french(english_text="Hello", project_id="ferrous-amphora-352613"):

    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

    location = "global"

    parent = f"projects/{'ferrous-amphora-352613'}/locations/{'My First Project'}"

    # Translate text from English to French
    response = client.translate_text(
        request={
            "location": location,
            "parent": parent,
            "contents": [english_text],
            "mime_type": "text/plain",  # 
            "source_language_code": "en-US",
            "target_language_code": "fr",
        }
    )

    # Display the translation for each input text provided
    for translation in response.translations:
        print("Translated text: {}".format(translation.translated_text))



# Translates french to english
# Initialize Translation client
def french_to_english(french_text="Bonjour", project_id="ferrous-amphora-352613"):
    """Translating Text."""

    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

    location = "global"

    parent = f"projects/{'ferrous-amphora-352613'}/locations/{'MyFirstProject'}"

    # Translate text from English to French
    response = client.translate_text(
        request={
            "location": location,
            "parent": parent,
            "contents": [french_text],
            "mime_type": "text/plain",  # 
            "source_language_code": "fr",
            "target_language_code": "en",
        }
    )

    # Display the translation for each input text provided
    for translation in response.translations:
        print("Translated text: {}".format(translation.translated_text))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

Comment: And use this: `if __name__ == "__main__": do_something`

Comment: @Bill Torcaso, Appreciate for the fix. I have been scratching my head on so many errors in this code for the past few days haha.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is an `__init__.py` file inside the directory as well.  I have been stuck trying to figure the same situation out and it ended up being I was missing that file.

Comment: Just added the file, realized I forgot to create it, thanks again and appreciate it @alexpdev

Comment: @MashCode20  So was that the problem?

Comment: the if statement at the end of the unit test I changed the .main formatting and added the machinetranslation. folder to the import at the top of my imports. Also apparently there was an with os.environ function, every time I tried to run the test it would point to an error there so I deleted it from translator.py and added the __init__.py and the test ran ok.

Comment: @MashCode20  Cool glad you figured it out.